# Find the value of $R$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n! \cdot (\ln 3)^n} = 3^x, \forall x \in (-R,R)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, geometric-series

I am not quite sure how to finish this exercise:

> Find the value of $R$ such that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n! \cdot (\ln 
>  3)^n} = 3^x, \forall x \in (-R,R)$$

I am honestly lost after I verify that the power series converges:

$$\begin{align*}
a_n &= \frac{x^n}{n! \cdot (\ln 3)^n}\\
a_{n+1} &= \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)! \cdot (\ln 3)^{n+1}}
\end{align*}
$$
The ratio between the two and the limit are shown below:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{x}{(n+1) \cdot \ln 3}\\
\\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\vert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\vert &= \frac{\vert x \vert}{\ln 3} \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1} = 0
\end{align*}
$$

So as I mentioned, I am not sure what to do next. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what denotes $R$ here?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sorry, let me fix that

Comment: @bru1987 Are you sure that it is $\frac{x}{\ln(3)}$ instead of $x \ln(3)$?

Comment: MathLover Has solved the problem for you.

Comment: @MathLover do you mean when evaluating the limit? So $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ was evaluated incorrectly?

Comment: @zhw. not sure how. Should I use Fourier Series here?

Comment: You should not try to find this.Mclaren series coefficients are unique(if they exist) if you find them for right hand side they wont be equal to left.So it will not exist.

Comment: I'm not even going to do this in an aswer. By the definition of the exponential function: $$3^x=e^{ x \ln 3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n (\ln 3)^n}{n!}$$ You see the problem here?

Comment: @YuriyS I actually don't, which shows me this is further than my understanding. I was actually thinking on a Maclaurin/Taylor series solution but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: $$\frac{x}{\ln 3} \neq x \ln 3$$ unless $x=0$. This has no solution. Likely a typo as many people said

Comment: If the assignment is quoted correctly, then the answer is **no solution**, because we can't set $R=0$ as $(0,0)$ is the empty set

Comment: @YuriyS I see, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It's possible the problem is misstated as @MathLover suggested in a comment. If it's not misstated, recall that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{u^n}{n!}= e^u$ and let $u=x/\ln 3.$

Comment: I see @zhw. This exercise is not intuitive at all to me. Let me try to find out if this is a typing mistake from the teachers notes. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @zhw. yes the description of the exercise is correct.

Comment: @bru1987 OK, this makes it easy. There is no such $R$ as in the comments of Yuriy S

Answer (score -1):

The $\ln 3$ does not matter.
The series converges for
all $x$.

As you have shown,
$|a_{n+1}/a_n| \to 0$.
The $\ln 3$ does 
not affect this,
so it still holds
with any constant.
This means that the series converges.

Comment: But the question is not whether it converges or not

Comment: So $R = \infty$.

Comment: @ martycohen, have you read the question? It is not asking for the radius of convergence. It is asking for the interval where the equation holds. Which is nowhere. Because $$\frac{x}{\log 3} \neq x \ln 3$$ unless $x=0$, but we can't write $R=0$, because then $(0,0)$ would be the empty set